# django - check which fields have only null values

Tags: django, null, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a specific `QuerySet` named `qs`. What would be an efficient way to query which model fields have only `null` values in the database for all `qs` records?
Alternatively - How would you fetch all fields which have at least one value which is not `null`, and only them?

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood you correctly, first case is - fetch only that objects, in which every field is Null:

```
qs.filter(**{'{0}__isnull'.format(field.name): True for field in self.model._meta.fields})
```

And second case - fetch only that objects, in which at least one field is not Null:

```
from django.db.models import Q

qs.filter(reduce(lambda res, x: res | x, map(Q, [('{0}__isnull'.format(field.name), False) for field in self.model._meta.fields]), Q()))
```

but I think second case equivalent to `qs.all()` because anyway you have filled `id` field ... for exclude `id` field replace `self.model._meta.fields` with `self.model._meta.fields[1:]`

To test code replace that chunk:

```
.format(field.name), False) for field in self.model._meta.fields
```

with

```
.format(field_name), False) for field_name in ('some_field1', 'some_field2', )
```